# how to create mysql databse backup if using in command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, database-backups

I am using MySQL in command line . I need to create backup of my database as I am afraid that if any virus attacks my laptop then I need to format it and my database will be lost .
Please tell me how to create backup of my database .   .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clone MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551301/clone-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) utility from command line like

```
mysqldump -u test -ptest <DB_NAME> > Backfile.mysql
```