# Database duplicacy

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a database in phpmyadmin. I am trying to export my tables in sql format. the export file is generated with nothing in it but when I try to export and save file in csv or json format data gets saved. When I import the csv or json file the import fails without giving any error. Can't understand why. 
I want to duplicate my complete database from one system to another. How can I do so?

Comment: Is this what your looking for? - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551301/clone-mysql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551301/clone-mysql-database)

Comment: If you try to export just one (small) table, what happens?