# copying mysql db tables from one db to another

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, phpmyadmin

I have 2 joomla sites.

1 with an component already installed and data present.

And a 2nd site which currently doesn't have the component installed, but I intend to install it and id like to copy the db data from the 1st site to the 2nd.

I have identified the tables in the db to copy from the 1st db to the 2nd, and both databases are on the same host, but im unsure on how to run the SQL command.

Any help would be much appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675289/cloning-a-mysql-database-on-the-same-mysql-instance

Answer (score 1):

It is as easy as this if you have same server location e.g both are on localhost

Suppose one table is `joom` with db prefix `b7gdj` and another table `joomla` with db prefix `z3djq` and you want to copy tables `z3djq_eventmanagement_events` and `z3djq_eventmanagement_attachments` from joomla to joom database. You can simply run this query in sql:

```
CREATE TABLE joom.b7gdj_eventmanagement_attachments SELECT * FROM joomla.z3djq_eventmanagement_attachments;
CREATE TABLE joom.b7gdj_eventmanagement_events SELECT * FROM joomla.z3djq_eventmanagement_events;
```