# mysqldump syntax error - password being used as database name

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

I'm trying to duplicate a MySQL (5.5.64-MariaDB) database on the same server by following this guide: [Cloning a MySQL database on the same MySql instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675289/cloning-a-mysql-database-on-the-same-mysql-instance)

The accepted answer didn't work so I reviewed the docs over at MySQL and found that the [mysqldump Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-summary) used `--user` and `--password` instead of the `-u` and `-p` flags on the linked post.

When I execute this:

```
mysqldump --user myUser --password myPassword dev_db | mysql -umyUser -pmyPassword staging_db
```

It firstly asks me to enter a password:

> Enter password:

So I enter `myPassword` although unsure why as it's given in the arguments list.

Then it gives the following error:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1049: "Unknown database 'myPassword'" when selecting the database

If I try entering the `--username` and `--password` *without spaces*:

```
mysqldump --usermyUser --passwordmyPassword dev_db | mysql -umyUser -pmyPassword staging_db
```

It errors

> mysqldump: unknown option '--usermyUser'

The intention of this is to copy `dev_db` into a database called `staging_db`. Both of these databases exist on the same server. The username/password I'm using has full access to every database on the MySQL instance.

Why doesn't this work?

If I use:

```
$ mysql -umyUser -pmyPassword
```

It connects without any issue and gives me the MariaDB command prompt.

Server is running CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

Database version:

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: If you read the Accepted answer there is a subtile difference between your attempt at `mysqldump` and the answer HINT `--password=<pwd>` !== `--passwordmyPassword`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a space before the password.

```
--password=myPassword
```

or

```
-pmyPassword
```

When the `--password` option doesn't have a directly connected parameter, it means to prompt for the password.