# How do I rename a MySQL schema?

Tags: mysql, database, rename, mysql-workbench

Is there a MySQL statement for renaming a schema? I know about `RENAME {DATABASE | SCHEMA} db_name TO new_db_name;`, but that statement "was found to be dangerous and was removed in MySQL 5.1.23" (as they mention in [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-database.html)).

I was also trying to do it using MySQL Workbench. I tried right clicking on the schema, and then alter schema. But they don't let you change its name in there.

So how do people rename databases?

Comment: There are already some answers here at SO that might help with your issue: [how-does-one-rename-a-schema-in-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490515/how-does-one-rename-a-schema-in-mysql) [cloning-a-mysql-database-on-the-same-mysql-instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675289/cloning-a-mysql-database-on-the-same-mysql-instance) [how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name)

Answer (score 21):

If you're on the Model Overview page you get a tab with the schema. If you rightclick on that tab you get an option to "edit schema". From there you can rename the schema by adding a new name, then click outside the field. This goes for MySQL Workbench 5.2.30 CE

Edit: On the model overview it's under Physical Schemata

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm not on the Model Overview page. Isn't there a MySQL statement to rename a schema?

Comment: Ok I misunderstood then;) Thought you were modeling the DB. See you've updated the question with more details now so a fool like me can't misunderstand it;)

Comment: Using MySQL Workbench 5.2.44 this doesn't work for me. I can change the schemata name in the edit field, but it doesn't have any effect on the actual physical schema I reverse-engineered the model from.