# Rename a database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am developing a web project using Java and MySQL. I am using Mysql Workbench. I started the work but now I need to change the database name. I tried

```
ALTER DATABASE Test MODIFY NAME = NewTest
```

and

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE Test
SET SINGLE_USER 
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
ALTER DATABASE Test MODIFY NAME = NewTest
GO
ALTER DATABASE NewTest
SET MULTI_USER 
GO
```

But these two are showing syntax error. What is the proper way to change database name in MySQL?

Comment: If you're getting an error, you should include the error itself in your post so that people can better understand what the problem might be.

Comment: Both are showing syntax error

Comment: Right, but what's the actual text of the error?

Comment: You question is probably already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545634/how-do-i-rename-a-mysql-schema

Comment: ALTER DATABASE Test_new MODIFY NAME = pareeksha Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MODIFY NAME = pareeksha'

Comment: USE master
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE Test_new 
 SET SINGLE_USER 
 WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE Test_new MODIFY NAME = pareeksha
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE NewTest
 SET MULTI_USER 
 GO Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GO
 ALTER DATABASE Test_new 
 SET SINGLE_USER 
 WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
 GO
 ALTER DA'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming a schema is not possible in MySQL. For the correct ALTER SCHEMA syntax see [the online manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-database.html).

Comment: Thank you... I have renamed using the forward engineering method means not renamed, created one new database which contain all tables and data of the current database

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code from a Microsoft Windows command prompt:

cd %ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin

```
mysqldump -u username -p -v olddatabase > olddbdump.sql
mysqladmin -u username -p create newdatabase
mysql -u username -p newdatabase < olddbdump.sql
```