# MySQL Workbench! add prefix to all tabels

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to set table prefix in MySQL workbench?
For example: I have created complete schema(table_1, table_2, table_3, ... table_N), and want to ask Workbench to add prefix to each table inside this schema on executing Forward Engineering.
Want to see in SQL script something like that

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`myprefix_table_1`...
```

Comment: you can execute the forward engineering. save the script as file and modify the script with find & replace pattern?

Comment: @krishKM, this is kludge, not a solution... Hope somebody know how to configure Workbench

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having your model or EER open, select Tools --> Catalog --> "Give a Prefix to All Tables in Catalog" from the menu.

Comment: thanks! Can you also tell me how to remove database name from SQL Script? i have found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545634/how-do-i-rename-a-mysql-schema). But this only gives possibility to rename and not to remove.. want something like this : `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'myprefix_table_1'`

Comment: In the forward engineer wizard, while on Options tab (second step), uncheck the "Generate DROP SCHEMA" and the script will end up with the CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS 'myprefix_table_1' command.

Comment: Don't help unchecking this option, but helps to check this option "Omit SchemaQualifier in Object Names" in that second step. Thank you for help!